write log into new file per 10 seconds while getting log from another application
I have go application which takes log from another binary application which is also go application. I want to write log in new file per 10 seconds.
But the problem is still writing in first log file no matter how many log files are created.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // Initialize the ticker to trigger every minute
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Minute / 10)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    // Create a channel to receive ticker events
    tickerCh := ticker.C

    logFolderPath := "./log/"
    // Initialize the first log file
    filename := generateFilename()
    logFile, err := os.OpenFile(logFolderPath+filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error opening log file:", err)
        return
    }
    defer logFile.Close()

    // Commands to execute sequentially
    cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "./ledplayer")

    // Connect command's stdout and stderr to pipes
    cmd.Stdout = logFile
    cmd.Stderr = logFile

    // Start the command
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Command started successfully. Log stored in", filename)

    // Loop to handle ticker events
    for range tickerCh {
        // Close the current log file
        err := logFile.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error closing log file:", err)
            return
        }

        log.Printf("%#v\n", logFile)

        // Generate a new filename for the next minute
        filename := generateFilename()

        // Open the new log file
        logFile, err = os.OpenFile(logFolderPath+filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error opening log file:", err)
            return
        }

        // Print the new log file name
        fmt.Println("Log file switched to", filename)

        // Update command's stdout and stderr to write to the new log file
        cmd.Stdout = logFile
        cmd.Stderr = logFile
    }

    // Wait for the command to finish before exiting
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error waiting for command to finish:", err)
    }
}

func generateFilename() string {
    // Generate filename with the current date and time
    return time.Now().Format("2006-01-02_15-04_05") + "_ledplayer.log"
}

I did creating new file every 10 seconds. Now I still have problems writing log in new file.

I guess you can't reuse the same cmd, you need to kill old cmd and start a new process.

I can't kill that process. It has to run a long time.
Also every 10 seonds is just for development purpose, It can be one log file per day.

I believe the following code will meet your need. Basically, instead of looping through the ticker's signal channel, use select. See below:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

type logWriter struct {
    C chan []byte
}

func (l logWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    l.C <- p
    return len(p), nil
}

func newChannelWriter() logWriter {
    return logWriter{
        C: make(chan []byte, 10),
    }
}

func main() {
    // Initialize the ticker to trigger every minute
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 10)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    logFolderPath := "./log/"
    // Initialize the first log file
    filename := generateFilename()
    logFile, err := os.OpenFile(logFolderPath+filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error opening log file:", err)
        return
    }
    defer logFile.Close()

    // Commands to execute sequentially
    cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "./ledplayer")

    // Connect command's stdout and stderr to pipes
    thisLogWriter := newChannelWriter()
    cmd.Stdout = thisLogWriter
    cmd.Stderr = thisLogWriter

    // Start the command
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Command started successfully: ", filename)

    // Loop to handle ticker events
    endChan := make(chan interface{}, 1)
    defer func() {
        endChan <- true
        close(endChan)
    }()

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-endChan:
                return
            case <-ticker.C:
                // Close the current log file
                if err := logFile.Close(); err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Error closing log file:", err)
                    return
                }

                // Generate a new filename for the next minute
                filename := generateFilename()

                // Open the new log file
                logFile, err = os.OpenFile(logFolderPath+filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Error opening log file:", err)
                    return
                }

                // Print the new log file name
                fmt.Println("Log file switched to", filename)
            case content := <-thisLogWriter.C:
                if _, err := logFile.Write(content); err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Error writing log:", err)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }()

    // Wait for the command to finish before exiting
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error waiting for command to finish:", err)
    }
    if err := logFile.Close(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error closing log file:", err)
        return
    }
}

func generateFilename() string {
    // Generate filename with the current date and time
    return time.Now().Format("2006-01-02_15-04_05") + "_ledplayer.log"
}

I redirected the process' logs to a channel, and write the log received in the channel to files.

this is my small attempt and it may not be effective. I omitted some errors, just hoping for reference value.
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // Initialize the ticker to trigger every minute
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Minute / 10)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    // Create a channel to receive ticker events
    tickerCh := ticker.C

    logFolderPath := "./log/"

    tmpFile, _ := os.CreateTemp("", "tmp_example")
    defer tmpFile.Close()

    // Commands to execute sequentially
    cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "./ledplayer")
    cmd.Stdout = tmpFile
    cmd.Stderr = tmpFile

    // Start the command
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }

    cmdStopCh := make(chan int)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(2)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        // Wait for the command to finish before exiting
        err = cmd.Wait()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error waiting for command to finish:", err)
        }
        // Notification End
        cmdStopCh <- 1
    }()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(tmpFile)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            // Create new log file
            filename := generateFilename()
            logFile, err := os.OpenFile(logFolderPath+filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error opening log file:", err)
                return
            }
            
            // Read from scanner and write to logFile
            for scanner.Scan() {
                logFile.WriteString(scanner.Text() + "\n")
                select {
                case <-tickerCh: // switch to new log file
                    break
                case <-cmdStopCh: // cmd is exited
                    logFile.Close()
                    return
                default:

                }
            }
            logFile.Close()
        }
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}

func generateFilename() string {
    // Generate filename with the current date and time
    return time.Now().Format("2006-01-02_15-04_05") + "_ledplayer.log"
}


It is creating new file per second or maybe per iteration. also doesn't write log into file.
I also tried to modify to create per minute, also doesn't work.
